# Chart JS - Disable lines and Uncheck legends by default

Tags: angular, chart.js

I am using Chart JS in Angular application and displaying 4 lines in LINE chart and displaying legends for each lines. Y-Axis 1 showing two lines and Y-Axis 2 showing two lines. I want to display only Y-Axis 1 lines by default when chart is loading. And I want to display Y-Axis 2 lines by click on uncheck legends. Please help me to do that?

Answer (score 1):

After creating the chart, you can retrieve its metadata through [`.getDatasetMeta(index)`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getdatasetmetaindex), change the hidden attribute of the desired datasets, then [update](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.7.0/developers/updates.html#updating-charts) the chart.

```
const chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  ...
});

chart.getDatasetMeta(2).hidden = true;    
chart.getDatasetMeta(3).hidden = true;    
chart.update();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the 'hidden'. I'm using Flask, on the frontend where I created one of the lines that I wanted to be auto disable I set `hidden: true` and that solved it for me.